# Google analytics on android app using fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, google-analytics

I am trying to add Google Analytics to my current app but I can't understand how to implement it in my app code.
I would like to put it on several fragments, below is one of the classes.

I am using Google's guide :
[https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/#activity-or-fragment][1]
And I still don't understand how to connect it to my current pages.

These are my codes :

LoginActivity2.java:

```
package com.example.tomgoldberg.tasker;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.google.android.gms.analytics.HitBuilders;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker;

/**
 * Created by TomGoldberg on 20.3.16.
 */
public class LoginActivity2 extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener , View.OnFocusChangeListener {
    static FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    private static final String TAG = "LoginActivity2";

    View myView;
    String email , password;
    EditText _emailTextView;
    EditText _passwordTextView;
    private Button _logInView;
    private Button _signup;

    boolean verEmail = false;
    boolean verPass = false;

    boolean insert = false;
    private Tracker mTracker;

    //static DatabaseHelper _myDB;
    FragmentActivity faActivity  ;


    public LoginActivity2() {
        //Functions.initializeData_forPendingTasks();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_login, container, false);
        fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        MyApplication application = (MyApplication) faActivity.getApplication();
        mTracker = application.getDefaultTracker();

        //Functions._drawerH1 = (TextView)myView.findViewById(R.id.navigationDrawer_h1);
        //Functions._drawerH2 = (TextView)myView.findViewById(R.id.navigationDrawer_h2);


        _logInView = (Button)myView.findViewById(R.id.loginBottun);
        _logInView.setOnClickListener(this);

        _signup = (Button)myView.findViewById(R.id.signUp_button);
        _signup.setOnClickListener(this);

        _emailTextView = (EditText)myView.findViewById(R.id.email_login_text);
        //_emailTextView.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);

        _passwordTextView = (EditText)myView.findViewById(R.id.password_login_text);
        //_passwordTextView.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);

        faActivity = getActivity();
        Functions._myDB = new DatabaseHelper(faActivity);
        Functions.insert();
        Functions.initializeData_forAllTasksFragment();
        Functions.initializeData_forPendingTasks();
        Functions.initializeData_forPriorityTasks();
        Functions.initializeData_forCategoryTasks();

        return myView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if ( v.getId() == _logInView.getId() ){
            email = _emailTextView.getText().toString();
            password = _passwordTextView.getText().toString();
            try{
                 if(  Functions.checkingManager(email,password)  ){
                     Snackbar.make(myView.findViewById(R.id.Login1mainLayout), "Welcome back manager " + Functions._userName , Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                             .setAction("Action", null).show();
                     try{
                         NavigationDrawer._drawerH1.setText(Functions._userName);
                         NavigationDrawer._drawerH2.setText(Functions._userEmail);
                     } catch (Exception E){
                         System.out.println("Unable to change...--> "+E.getMessage());
                     }
                     Fragment fragment = new MainMenu();
                     android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                     transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
                     transaction.addToBackStack("stack_MainMenu_after_LOGIN");
                     transaction.commit();

                    }
                 else if ( Functions.checkingMember(email, password)){
                     Snackbar.make(myView.findViewById(R.id.Login1mainLayout), "Welcome back member " + Functions._userName , Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                             .setAction("Action", null).show();
                     try{
                         NavigationDrawer._drawerH1.setText(Functions._userName);
                         NavigationDrawer._drawerH2.setText(Functions._userEmail);
                     } catch (Exception E){
                         System.out.println("Unable to change...--> "+E.getMessage());
                     }
                     Fragment fragment = new MainMenu();
                     android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                     transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
                     transaction.addToBackStack("stack_MainMenu_after_LOGIN");
                     transaction.commit();
                 }
                else {
                    _logInView.setError("Some error");
                    Snackbar.make(myView.findViewById(R.id.Login1mainLayout), "Please provide your Email and Password", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();
                    _logInView.setError(null);
                }
            } catch (Exception e){
                _logInView.setError("Some error");
                Snackbar.make(myView.findViewById(R.id.Login1mainLayout), "Please provide your Email and Password", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
                _logInView.setError(null);
            }
        }
        else if ( v.getId() == _signup.getId() ){
            Fragment fragment = new SignUpAsManager();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack("stack_SignUp");
            transaction.commit();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange( View v , boolean hasFocus ) {
        if ( v.getId() == _emailTextView.getId() && !hasFocus ) {
            verifyEmail();
            _emailTextView = (EditText)myView.findViewById(R.id.email_login_text);
        }
        if (v.getId() == _passwordTextView.getId() && !hasFocus) {
            verifyPassword();
            _passwordTextView = (EditText) myView.findViewById(R.id.password_login_text);
        }
    }

    public void verifyEmail(){
        String emailToCheck = _emailTextView.getText().toString();
        if (  TextUtils.isEmpty(emailToCheck) || Functions.hasNoLetters(emailToCheck) || Functions.isEmail(emailToCheck)) {
            _emailTextView.setError("Please Provide Your Email Address");
            verEmail = false;
        }
        else if(  TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(emailToCheck)  ) {
            _emailTextView.setError("Email Address Only");
            verEmail = false;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("verifyEmail");
            try{
                verEmail = true ;
                _logInView.setError(null);
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    public void verifyPassword(){
        String passwordToCheck = _passwordTextView.getText().toString();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(passwordToCheck)||Functions.hasNoLetters(passwordToCheck)){
            _passwordTextView.setError("Please Provide Your Password");
            System.out.println("verifyPassword");
            verPass = false;
        }
        else {
            try{
                verPass = true;
                _logInView.setError(null);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                System.out.println("verifyPassword");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        Log.i(TAG, "Setting screen name: " + name);
        mTracker.setScreenName("Image~" + name);
        mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());

        mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
                .setCategory("Action")
                .setAction("Share")
                .build());

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

MyApplication.java:

```
package com.example.tomgoldberg.tasker;

import android.app.Application;

import com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker;

/**
 * Created by tommyahav on 07/04/2016.
 */
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private Tracker mTracker;
    synchronized public Tracker getDefaultTracker() {
        if (mTracker == null) {
            GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
            // To enable debug logging use: adb shell setprop log.tag.GAv4 DEBUG
            mTracker = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker);
        }
        return mTracker;
    }
}
```

Analytics.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:ignore="TypographyDashes">

<!--Replace placeholder ID with your tracking ID-->
<string name="ga_trackingId">UA-75923329-1</string>

<!--Enable automatic activity tracking-->
<bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>

<!--Disable automatic exception tracking-->
<bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">false</bool>

</resources>
```

Thank you for helping.
Tom

Comment: ya.  it is right.. What's your problem. what error you got, when running the application. ?

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> [xml/global_tracker] /Users/tommyahav/Downloads/Tasker-master 4/app/src/main/res/xml/global_tracker.xml [xml/global_tracker] /Users/tommyahav/Downloads/Tasker-master 4/app/build/generated/res/google-services/debug/xml/global_tracker.xml: Error: Duplicate resources

Comment: It's not working,I erased the duplicate file but I am still getting errors. Now I am getting that : name ---> Error:(203, 43) error: cannot find symbol variable name, under:     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) on LoginActivity.java part. name should be the page name that needs to be shown on google analytics page.

Comment: For the above error, you didn't declare the **name** variable and also didn't assign any values for the **name** variable on the onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) method.

Comment: How I can do it? How to implement this to work ?

Answer (score 1):

Those screen names and events of the google analytics won't appear in your application log file.

You have to go [Google Analytics website](https://analytics.google.com/) and log in with your email account which you used to create the configuration file.

After login you have to choose your project **Default view** and then you will be redirected to your app overview page.

And that page provided with the menus on the left side. you have to select **Real Time --> Screens** option to watch out the current actions.

Every action you made will be reflected after 3-5 minutes only.

Comment: I've entered my Tracking ID that I got from Google Analytics website, I've also downloaded the .json file and add it under - app folder on my project files. I am trying to add GA ( google analytics ) to my current project, and see the traffic of my app from GA screen. I saw several explanations about it and they add some code with the activities they want to follow.

Comment: Okk.. So, now whats your problem. In which way you are not tracking the result. Please explain me much better .

Comment: I want to know how implement Google's code on my project.